# Can a beis din rule in a case where they're biased?

Tags: halacha, money, beit-din-court

Can a beis din rule in monetary matters that concern them? For instance can they rule that Simon owes Levi and themselves? Or must it be brought to a unbiased beis din?

Answer (score 6):

Shulchan Arukh CM 7:12

> כל דבר שיש לדיין בו צד הנאה אינו יכול לדון עליו
>   Any matter that the judge has some benefit from, he is not allowed to judge it.